# WebSQL chrome admin tool

Tags: sql, google-chrome, admin, web-sql

I am building an app using a web SQL database. I remember seeing somewhere that there is a way using Google Chrome to inspect the web SQL databases, 
however I can't find the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inspect databases with Chrome DevTools using the [Resources Panel](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/resources.html).

Answer (score 3):

Using PersistenceJS there is a persistence.reset API which will wipe the database clean.
[PersistenceJS Site](http://persistencejs.org)

For developing / testing purposes, you can view content and delete webSQL, IndexedDB, cookies, etc by searching for your domain name at this URL in Chrome:

```
chrome://settings/cookies
```

There, you can delete all the storage for a domain or just certain local storage entities. Yes, the URL implies just 'cookies', but the interface at this URL includes all types of offline storage.

It would be great I think if the Chrome developer tools interface had the ability to right-click and delete a data storage entity in the Resources tab along with inspecting the content. But for now, all I know of is the settings/cookies URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to open developer tools on Chrome.
Then go to resources tab (pink oval in screenshot below)
When there click on WebSQL and you will see list of databases that you can expand (red oval in screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: Just a point to note that as of today the `Resources` tab is not there at all in chrome. It got renamed to `Application` tab